# Multiple properties for visible ngOption value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options

I have an object similar to this:

```
$scope.division = [
  {
    name: "Tom",
    number: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Greg",
    number: 2
  }
];
```

Now in my HTML I'm using `ngOption` to display a drop down filled with values from the object.

```
<select data-ng-model="game.player1" data-ng-options="player.name for player in division">
  <option value="" disabled="true">Player 1</option>
</select>
```

This displays a drop down of names as expected. However, I want to actually display the name and number in the drop down. So for example if I hard-coded it:

```
<option>1 - Tom</option>
<option>2 - Greg</option>
```

I've tried various methods including stuff like this:

```
data-ng-options="player.number player.name for player in division"
```

But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to concatenate like so:

```
ng-options="(player.number + ' - ' + player.name) for player in division"
```

Comment: Ah yes of course! I did try something similar but must have got the syntax wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could just concatenate it in the expression itself.

```
<select data-ng-model="game.player1" 
    data-ng-options="(player.number + '-' + player.name) for player in division">
```

However i would do this on the controller to create that specific view model that needs to be bound, rather than doing it on the view.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
 
$scope.game ={player1: 1};
  
$scope.division = [
  {
    name: "Tom",
    number: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Greg",
    number: 2
  }
];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select data-ng-model="game.player1" data-ng-options="player.number as (player.number + '-' + player.name) for player in division">
  <option value="" disabled="true">Player 1</option>
</select>
  {{game.player1}}
  </div>
```

Comment: @Coop You could also look at using track by with a unique property (i.e probably player.number) or use select as syntax so that you can prebind values just with a plain object i.e $scope.game.player1 = {number:2} or just the id(which is unique)  $scope.game.player1 = 2 respectively. In your case you would need to pre-bind ng-model(if you are doing it) with the same object reference as in the array which sometimes makes you do unwanted work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a formatting function defined in your controller:

```
$scope.format = function(player) {
  return player.number + ' - ' + player.name;
};
```

Then mark it up like so:

```
data-ng-options="format(player) for player in division"
```